# REST using Jersey in Mule returning blank response through ajax

Tags: json, jquery, rest, jersey, mule

I am using Jersey to create a REST service in Mule 3. Using logger I could see the response in the server. However, I don't see the response in ajax call to the service. The response is blank when debug with Firebug. Appreciate for any help

```
INFO  2013-07-23 12:07:01,123 [[muletraining].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: from REST {"code":"200","message":"Successful","data":"SomeText"}
```

Mule Config file look like:

```
 <flow name="griduploaderFlow1" doc:name="griduploaderFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9099" path="grid" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="from request #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component class="com.mulesoft.training.GridUploaderImpl"/>
    </jersey:resources>
    <custom-transformer class="com.mulesoft.training.JerseyResponseTransformer" doc:name="Java" mimeType="application/json"/>
    <logger message="from REST #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Cross-domain origin issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't even see your first logger output, you don't have a problem with Jersey necessarily.
The "from request" log should appear before Jersey gets to play. If that doesn't happen, you need to make sure that your MULE is running properly.
Comment out the code from before the jersey element until the  closing tag:

```
<flow name="griduploaderFlow1" doc:name="griduploaderFlow1">
      <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9099" path="grid" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <logger message="from request #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<!--
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
    <component class="com.mulesoft.training.GridUploaderImpl"/>
</jersey:resources>
<custom-transformer class="com.mulesoft.training.JerseyResponseTransformer" doc:name="Java" mimeType="application/json"/>
<logger message="from REST #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
-->
</flow>
```

If this doesn't display you anything either, it's a generic mule issue and not Jersey.

If in your you do see the loggers but no exception and still no response, my bet would be to set the proper Content-Type on your HTTP component. Say, if it's set to image/png and you return 0 from Jersey, you will see nothing in the browser.
So it's important to tell the browser what is it that you are sending back in order for it to parse it and display it properly.